# Browser refresh by Ctrl+F5 in WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, page-refresh, browser-refresh

I have refreshed the browser in WebDriver using java as below code:

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

How can I do that by pressing Ctrl+F5 in WebDriver using Java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can use the WebDriver and Actions instance as below:

```
Actions actionObject = new Actions(driver);
actionObject.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.F5).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform‌​();
```

Comment: I ran the above code. Unfortunately, the following exception was occurred:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key Down / Up events only make sense for modifier keys.

Comment: Ctrl is a modifier key but F5 is not. You probably want to use actionObject.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.F5).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();

Comment: Thanks. The above code is helpful for me. "The method perform‌() is undefined for the type Actions" : this error was shown on above code. Small modified code is as below:
actionObject.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.F5).perform();